# GY-MAX30100 outputs high value for Heart Rate

Tags: embedded, nodemcu

In uploading the MAX30100_minimal in the example on the package MAX30100lib by Oxullo. I am getting a high value output for the heart rate but the SpO2 is already good.

I am using GY-MAX30100 to get both heart rate and SpO2. I am currently switching from both nodemcu v3 and lolin wemos d1 mini. So far, the MAX30100 outputs a high value for heart rate which ranges from 150 - 250 but the SpO2 is already good.

Is there any solution for this or should I change components or library usage. I already tried, changing the default configurations in the library such as the sampling rate, ledsCurrent, and others. I also tried using MAX30102, however uploading the example8 in the sparkfun library it does not execute and does a memory dump instead.

The library I am using for MAX30100 is MAX30100lib by Oxullo.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "MAX30100_PulseOximeter.h"

#define REPORTING_PERIOD_MS     1000

PulseOximeter pox;

uint32_t tsLastReport = 0;

void onBeatDetected()
{
    Serial.println("Beat!");
}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

    Serial.print("Initializing pulse oximeter..");

    if (!pox.begin()) {
        Serial.println("FAILED");
        for(;;);
    } else {
        Serial.println("SUCCESS");
    }

    pox.setIRLedCurrent(MAX30100_LED_CURR_7_6MA);
    pox.setOnBeatDetectedCallback(onBeatDetected);
}

void loop()
{
    pox.update();

    if (millis() - tsLastReport > REPORTING_PERIOD_MS) {
        Serial.print("Heart rate:");
        Serial.print(pox.getHeartRate());
        Serial.print("bpm / SpO2:");
        Serial.print(pox.getSpO2());
        Serial.println("%");

        tsLastReport = millis();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! will do so, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?  In particular this part: https://github.com/oxullo/Arduino-MAX30100#sketchy-beat-frequency-readouts